# get canvas pixels after fillText returns 0

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts

I was trying to get the pixel density of any character using HTML5 canvas with JavaScript, but context getImageData returns always an array which seems to be a pitch black rectangle (RGB = [0,0,0] always).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
var dcanvas = document.getElementById('char-canvas'),
  dcontext = dcanvas.getContext('2d');

function fontDensity(c) {
  dcanvas.height = 30;
  dcanvas.width = 30;
  dcontext.clearRect(0, 0, dcanvas.width, dcanvas.height);
  dcontext.font = "15px monospace";
  dcontext.fillStyle = "black";
  dcontext.textAlign = "center";
  dcontext.textBaseline = "middle";
  dcontext.fillText(c, dcanvas.width / 2, dcanvas.height / 2);
  var imgd = dcontext.getImageData(0, 0, dcanvas.width, dcanvas.height),
    pix = imgd.data,
    density = 0;
  // Read canvas pixels RGBA!
  for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    density += (pix[i] + pix[i + 1] + pix[i + 2]) / 3;
  }
  //density /= pix.length;
  return density;
}

console.log(fontDensity("a"));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="char-canvas" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default pixel value is black transparent so you will always have RGB returning 0 when the color is black.

To distinguish you need to use the alpha channel:

```
var density = (pix[i] + pix[i + 1] + pix[i + 2]) * (pix[i + 3] / 255) / 3;
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is just one way to do it of course. To avoid anti-aliased pixels to be part of the calculation you just use a threshold instead.

Comment: what a moron I was... the default "color" of the canvas is not white... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Funny , black return's zero in RGB 0 is black .
No need for setTimeout .

```js
//Globals

density = 0;
dcanvas = null;
dcontext = null;
imgd = null;
pix = null;

//make calculation
function GET () {
  
  for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    density += (pix[i] + pix[i + 1] + pix[i + 2]) / 3;
  }
  console.log(density)
  
}



function fontDensity(c) {
  dcanvas.height = 30;
  dcanvas.width = 30;
  dcontext.clearRect(0, 0, dcanvas.width, dcanvas.height);
  dcontext.font = "15px monospace";
  dcontext.fillStyle = "#100000";
  dcontext.textAlign = "center";
  dcontext.textBaseline = "middle";
  dcontext.fillText(c, dcanvas.width / 2, dcanvas.height / 2);
//dcontext.fillRect(0,0, dcanvas.width , dcanvas.height); 
  imgd = dcontext.getImageData(0, 0, dcanvas.width , dcanvas.height );
  pix = imgd.data; 
  GET ()
  
}

window.onload = function(){

dcanvas = document.getElementById('char-canvas');
dcontext = dcanvas.getContext('2d');

  fontDensity("a")

 
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="char-canvas" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
```